# Is is possible to transition a 2D noise function to another along with a sensible derivative?

Tags: function, interpolation, noise, derivative, blending

I have a noise function NoiseAt(x,y) that returns a noise value and two derivatives dx and dy.
I want to transition this function into another noise function OtherNoiseAt(x, y) that also returns both the noise and two derivatives.

It is Simplex noise based on the implementation found here:
https://github.com/simongeilfus/SimplexNoise/blob/master/include/Simplex.h

For example for x & y values greater than 1 the function **NoiseAt** should blend into the function **OtherNoiseAt** and finish blending when x & y values are greater than 2.

I have already tried lerping both the noise and the derivatives, but the resulting derivatives are invalid.

ie.

```
Lerp(NoiseAt(x, y), OtherNoiseAt(x, y), blending_factor)
```

(where the blending_factor is 0 when x & y values are both smaller than 1 and the blending_factor is 1 when x & y values are both greater than 2)

Is there a blending method than allows sensible derivatives to be maintained throughout the blend?

In other words, what is the body of this function:

```
Blend(noise1, dx1, dy1, noise2, dx2, dy2, factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your blending factor needs to be differentiable as well.

To see this, let's write out what `h = Lerp(f, g, a)` means:

```
h = af + (1-a)g
```

Everything is a function of `x` and `y` here, including `a` itself. Take the derivative using the chain rule (for simplicity of notation, I'm ignoring the fact that these things are two-dimensional):

```
h' = a'f + af' - a'g + (1-a)g'
```

So for `h'` to exist everywhere, we need `a'` to exist as well. However, you're not using `Lerp` everywhere, but only on the interval where the transition happens. It's as if you clamped `a` to the interval `[0, 1]` before passing it to `Lerp`. From your post, I gather that `a` looks something like this:

```
          0 if x < 1 and y < 1
a(x, y) = ? "in between"
          1 if x > 2 and y > 2
```

That's rather under-specified, so let's look at a one-dimensional case:

```
       0     if x < 1
a(x) = x - 1 if     1 ≤ x ≤ 2
       1     if             2 < x
```

This is a continuous function, but it's not differentiable at `x = 1` and `x = 2` because the slope suddenly changes.

There are several alternatives that do have a derivative everywhere. These are typically defined on the interval `0 ≤ x ≤ 1`, so you'll have to do some translation and maybe scaling before evaluating the function. The key when constructing these is to make sure that the derivative is zero at `x = 0` and `x = 1`.

For example, with a cosine shape:

```
       0               if x < 0
a(x) = 1 - cos(x/pi)/2 if     0 ≤ x ≤ 1
       1               if             1 < x
```

Or with a cubic spline (see also ["smoothstep"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep)):

```
       0         if x < 0
a(x) = 3x² - 2x³ if     0 ≤ x ≤ 1
       1         if             1 < x
```